# Python outputs string with newline character from external C program call

Tags: python, c, string

This is my first question, any feedback would be amazing.

I am calling a C program from Python3 and the string captured by my variable 
prints out the newline characters instead of processing a newline character.

Want this:
hello
world

I get:
b'hello\nworld'

I have this c program called find.c:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        printf("%s:\n%s\n\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Executed/Ran/Processed by Python3:

```
    import sys
    import subprocess

    user = sys.argv[1]
    item = sys.argv[2]

    out = subprocess.check_output(["./find", user, item])
    print(out)
```

Once again, the string "out" contains the "\n" instead of treating it like
a new line.

I've tried adding: universal_newlines=True and end="" to check_out() with no luck.

I've tried using Popen() and call() and they both still keep the "\n".

As a last note: I am outputting this string to a textarea in html. And yes I know the b'' is not actually part of the string.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EHHHH, I figured it out. For anyone interested I did the following:

```
    print(subprocess.check_output(["./find",user,item],universal_newlines=True))
```

I didn't actually try using universal_newlines=True exclusively.

Look at that my first accepted answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

In your out you need to strip the carriage return and new lines.

```
import sys
import subprocess

user = sys.argv[1]
item = sys.argv[2]

out = check_output(["./find", user, item]).strip()
print(out)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response! However, there was no output in the textarea html, I did however solve it. See my answer, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try this.  subprocess is returning a byte string, you want to print it as ascii characters.

```
print(out.decode('ascii'))
```